# Geometric Construction

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

"Given in position the points $A,B$ and $P$ and a segment $m$, draw through $P$ a line $r$ in such a way that  $A$ and $B$ be in opposite sides of $r$ and that the sum of the distances from $A$ and $B$ to $r$ be $m$."
Some hint of how to do it? Some link with the construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes a proof without words:

[image]
$$\phantom{\sum}$$

Comment: A concern: For $P$ in the above figure, the perpendicular $r$ drawn through $m$ and $P$ crosses $\overline{AB}$ and so passes between $A$ and $B$. But this looks only to be the case for a certain range of $P$; for instance, it appears to fail if we choose $P$ to be directly above the circle. (That might just mean that no construction exists for such $P$, but right now that subtlety isn't addressed.)